# My CodeCademy Game wont recognize "Phaser.game", How Can I Fix This?

Tags: javascript

When i am on a level on CodeCademy it works and it recognize the Phaser.game, but when i use it in my workspace it says this

```
/home/ccuser/workspace/sandbox-node-14-63692ccffea1e4eec12e8454/game.js:52
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
             ^

ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ccuser/workspace/sandbox-node-14-63692ccffea1e4eec12e8454/game.js:52:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 This is My Code
```

This is my code.

```
const config = {
  height: 320,
  width: 704,
  backgroundColor: 0x1aa604,
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
    update,
  }
}



function preload() {
  this.load.image('codey', 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/learn-phaser/codey.png');
}



function create() {
  gameState.codey = this.add.sprite(30, 60,
  "codey")
gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
}

function update() {
  if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.x += 5;
  }
  if (gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.x -= 5;
  }
  if (gameState.cursors.up.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.y -= 5;
  }
  if (gameState.cursors.down.isDown) {
    gameState.codey.y += 5;
  }
}


const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

const gameState = {}
```

`

Please Help Me. Im A Beginner.

I tried just copiyng the code from the level i made t my workspace on codecademy, but it didnt work.

Comment: Phaser doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in your code. That is probably why.

Comment: But i dont think i have to define it because its a built in object right? And It works on the "learn phaser.js" Lesson. And if not, how do i define making a scene/game, also isnt the 5th line in my code named scene suppost to make the background or the things on my game?

Comment: It might be a built-in object in the workspace environment of that lesson, but if you just copy the code without any reference from where you would get that object, you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Ohhh. Thats right, but how do i define phaser.game, Because i always thought it was a built in object, For me defining Phaser.game is like defining console.log

Comment: Either create it yourself or find a way to get the object used in the workspace.

Comment: But How Can i Make A Game Without using phaser.game?

Comment: You can download phaser from [here](https://phaser.io/download) as a JS file and then use it in your JS file.